# DNS A-record IP that resolves to another IP (something like CNAME A-record)

Tags: dns, resolve, a-records

If I own an IP (let's call it IP_A), is it possible to set it up so that any A record that points to it resolves to another IP (let's call it IP_B)?

For example:

mydomain.com has a A record that points to IP_A

IP_A resolves to IP_B

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Do a Google search for a tutorial on how DNS works.  [Like this one](http://oreilly.com/catalog/dns3/chapter/ch02.html).